# Android Debug Keytool Error

Tags: android, keytool

I can't seem to get the SHA1 string from running the keytool command. When I am prompted for the password for my debug key I enter "android" and after hitting enter I get a string of weird characters. Please see below.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias   androiddebugkey
-keystore C:\Users\CaduDesktop\.android\debug.keystore
 Enter keystore password:
☺☺♂♣ 071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
450428134123Z071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
☺☺☺♣ ♥é☺☼ 0é☺0é☺"0
☻é☺☺ ╡|¿t├▬╖Åδu▲dτw♦┤»Φ/        óq>ô¡╡jd♦0▐ï▬♀òy_4ƒ(|¼╒-▒ñ▄⌡Ii£ÿ◄f=╩Z¥ç▌   %É'a♂σQ¥
§¿ª∟sY↨ ■▀¢Öε═←┬-α≈π÷í¬«JÄ┌£↓àuJæ¬)⌡╔Cç┤3-ê╙♦ü¡-öæ½│↑♥]£4ß╩ó√♫êq·╛$CßÅ7%°k╗éπ→$Γ
ì¿q=cS♥|┘²'f⌐J@ò█¿∞?n→Ü♫ù►╣Åî└pÆ╝-2←/↕▌wT       Bz╝♥☺#¬¿♀înOS¿═Q☻♥☺ ☺ú!0▼0↔♠♥U↔♫
♦▬♦¶╜▌qH
¿wÉqδUΦ½┴«╖ÖëèN┬╪8╪`gφ ≡«lG]8√∙█p0Yú∩j8,╠ä{╘x"┘Σq±↨═I₧ú☼Γ%Y╨⌡mΣùg☻Uù╠↔
ƒh▌"µvë#è└I►∙ä⌠ræÇ♫²║G9á ¢─↑Y╠4ε╠G╨?åcù(K{Ω$τ↨k⌂±Rí╛┼ñ♦0"☼É3Wƒ1E╦▒¶ºZ_√V¼ê âß▀Φ╗
¶╕hG±çΦ½♂~♂∟êä|┌♣εKÉÄµ╨èê∙╙▬╛!Ñ
```

What Can I do to fix this?

Comment: Maybe your keystore got corrupted. Are you sure of its type and integrity?

Comment: Actually I had just ran the app and it created the debug file automatically in the folder, then I tried to run the keytool command and got the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I entered the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keyst­ore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Nice. The please accept your own answer to close the question ;)

Comment: got to wait to 2 days to do that :)